# calling helper method inside rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a helper with a method to check if a user is signed in:

sessions_helper.rb:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil? # if current user is not nil then user is signed in
  end
end
```

I want to test that a user is signed in after some action with rspec:

my_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "after clicking button" do
    before  {click_button someButton}
    it "should be signed in" do
      signed_in? != nil
    end
end
```

So how do I make my signed_in? method accessible by my spec? Do I just need to add:
`require 'sessions_helper'`? Am I better off putting something in my spec_helper.rb file so that this method is accessible to all my spec.rb files?

Comment: Don't forget to call `should`, your test is useless (but green) otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SessionsHelper
  describe "after clicking button" do
    before  {click_button someButton}
    it "should be signed in" do
      helper.signed_in? != nil
    end
  end
end
```

You can call the helper methods on the object "helper"